# progress bar function breaking after one call

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nrjw0Le/28/)

In the code provided if you click battle it will complete the battle action and fill the progress bar 3 times(equal to var auto) if you let it finish that and then click battle again the progress bar will reach val 25 and freeze. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
var auto = 3;
var nb = 0;

var progress = function(sec) {
    if($('#bar').val() === 0) {
    $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage").fadeIn(400);
  }
  if($('#bar').val() >= 75) {
    $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage").fadeOut(800);
  }
  var interval = 1000; //milliseconds 
  setTimeout(function() {     
    sec = sec + 25;
    $('#bar').val(sec);
    if (sec > 100) {
      $('#bar').val(0);
      sec = 0;
      nb++;
    }
    if (nb < auto) progress(sec); //call self with new value
  }, interval)
}

$('#battle').click(function() {  
  progress(0); //initialize progress bar
});
```

Comment: You only need reset "nb = 0;" again before call progress(0);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `nb` variable is not reset. Following code/condition should work:

```
if (nb < auto) 
  progress(sec);
else
  nb = 0;
```

See working **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nrjw0Le/30/)**